Uploading both data and files using nested arrays
I want to upload an array of documents, where each document contains a file and a type (number). The frontend will send the form data as shown in the image. What should the backend handle in Node.js using Multer?
enter image description here
When I use upload.array('images') or upload.array('images[]'), I encounter an error like 'unexpected file'. When I use upload.fields([{name: 'images[0][file]'}]), there is no error, but the length of the array is unknown, so I think this approach cannot be applied.
I can also try upload.any(). It keeps loading without returning a response.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Upload.any() works effectively :v
